# How do I extract the row index and predictions from a Caret model?

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a random forest model in Caret in R. I am running predictions on a table where the model predicts if the genes are dominant, recessive, or benign. Below is how I use the model and save the predictions.

```
library(caret)
library(data.table)
library(rstan)

predict = readRDS("model.RDS")
data = read("data.csv")
predictions = predict(predict, newdata = data)

write.table(predictions, "predictions.txt")
```

When I read the model.RDS object, I notice there's a section that reads $pred, which lists the prediction and also the row index. However, in my predictions.txt file, I only notice it contains the annotated predictions (dominant, recessive, or benign). Is there a way for me to extract both the row index and the pred columns so I can map the rows to the rows of another table?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If `predict` is the model object, the output is a named `list`.  We extract the component i.e. 'pred' with `$` or `[[`, then subset the columns that are needed from the `data.frame` `pred`

```
out <- predict$pred[c("pred", "rowIndex")]
```

Comment: will the rowIndex and pred be extractable if we use the caret object for predictions on a new dataset?

Comment: @britney Not sure what you meant.  The rowIndex and pred is stored in the model object